# how to block emails from helo=localhost.localdomain

Tags: spam

at my email server postfix, dovecot, amavis, spamassassin are blocking spam well, but some spam emails with bad HELO (`helo=localhost.localdomain / Received-spf ....envelope-from=<>; receiver=<UNKNOWN>`) passed and accepted as regular email. I would like block them, but where to setup this? I tried to look up at internet where to set up this, but without success

Postfix `main.cf` setup

```
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
    reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
    reject_unknown_helo_hostname

smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unknown_sender_domain,
    reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname,
    reject_unknown_client_hostname,
    reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch
    
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    reject_unauth_pipelining,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname,
    permit_mynetworks,
    reject_unauth_destination,
    check_policy_service unix:private/policyd-spf,
    reject_rhsbl_helo dbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rhsbl_reverse_client dbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rhsbl_sender dbl.spamhaus.org,
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
    permit_dnswl_client swl.spamhaus.org
```

Headers from email:

```
Dkim-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=intel-consalt.com; s=default; h=Date:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Content-Type :From:Message-ID:List-Unsubscribe:MIME-Version:To:Subject:Sender:Reply-To:Cc: Content-ID:Content-Description:Resent-Date:Resent-From:Resent-Sender: Resent-To:Resent-Cc:Resent-Message-ID:In-Reply-To:References:List-Id: List-Help:List-Subscribe:List-Post:List-Owner:List-Archive; bh=IzBRElKnftTU4iCUH+Xr++CrzKttzhK/7pnskykot/A=; b=VmtVsNm6CmWHvQ3M+dAVjqFZn5 Zr4i4n3ZLEXaMn4aR/d+2tMOkAD9HC/Ce2Zu0UUT+qomEjKVLYlC11yFpSEODxMbscNN64w3OSmDd n63QIwOYzcgDXoQjHqS9pIsRKS7jM3VWLsou3PBmOWz3s0E9pi1yzrv0aKb7tFGv+Dko=;
X-Spam-Score: -0.087
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Spam-Flag: NO
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-0.087 tagged_above=-999 required=3.2 tests=[DKIM_SIGNED=0.1, DKIM_VALID=-0.1, DKIM_VALID_AU=-0.1, HTML_MESSAGE=0.001, SPF_HELO_NONE=0.001, T_REMOTE_IMAGE=0.01, URIBL_BLOCKED=0.001] autolearn=disabled
X-Antivirus: avast (VPS 21031910)
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=b1_b1up5fsi7ewok34q2.KANROcvT; charset="UTF-8"
Received-Spf: None (no SPF record) identity=helo; client-ip=78.128.76.57; helo=vps.uzhgorod.work; envelope-from=<>; receiver=<UNKNOWN> 
Delivered-To: jiri.xxxx@domain.cz
X-Authenticated-Sender: 
Received: from mx1.domain.com by mx1.domain.com with LMTP id nXHtB+VqVWD+JQAASQADjA (envelope-from <>) for <jiri.xxxx@domain.cz>; Sat, 20 Mar 2021 04:24:21 +0100
Received: from localhost (mx1.domain.com [127.0.0.1]) by mx1.domain.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id C93E462A9E1 for <jiri.xxxx@domain.cz>; Sat, 20 Mar 2021 04:24:20 +0100 (CET)
Received: from mx1.domain.com ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (mx1.domain.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024) with ESMTP id v_IwzA6QRfnL for <jiri.xxxx@domain.cz>; Sat, 20 Mar 2021 04:24:20 +0100 (CET)
Received: from vps.uzhgorod.work (vps.uzhgorod.work [78.128.76.57]) by mx1.domain.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 3956C624061 for <jiri.xxxx@domain.cz>; Sat, 20 Mar 2021 04:24:20 +0100 (CET)
Received: from [77.83.202.162] (port=48400 helo=localhost.localdomain) by vps.uzhgorod.work with esmtpsa  (TLS1) tls TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (Exim 4.94) id 1lNSH1-0000zn-Ow for jiri.xxxx@domain.cz; Sat, 20 Mar 2021 05:27:35 +0200
```

Comment: Please show more verbose Postfix processing log regarding that suspicious mail ("connect from ...", and so on), also show headers of that mail.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov - Logs from server I will have later. My question is, why policy  smtpd_helo_restrictions accepts unvalid HELO ...

Comment: Your headers look really strange. Postfix puts all Received blocks *above* everything else, and those have many line breaks. Probably Dovecot rearranged them, which is **very bad** and if this is the case this single argument is enough for me to never ever use Dovecot and recommend to boycott it completely. Now I'm done with my anger, more to the topic. Technically `localhost.localdomain` is valid FQDN hostname and it might be "known" to your system (i.e. it can resolve it). Also `mynetworks` could have permitted that mail. Please, post a complete `postconf -Mf` for us to not to guess things.

Comment: Also, why rearranging headers is so bad: we don't know for sure which header is added by your server and which is not. It seems `localhost.localdomain` is not HELO which was presented to your server, but to `vps.uzhgorod.work`, and if your server is mx1.domain.com, then the HELO hostname it was presented with was `vps.uzhgorod.work`. It was this hostname `vps.uzhgorod.work` which was tested by `smtpd_hello_restrictions` tests, and indeed it is completely correct and fine hostname and so it passed all of them successfully.

Comment: Congratulations, now you have problems with Dovecot, or something else which rearranging headers. By the RFC5321 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5321#section-3.7.2 `Received` headers always *prepended* to the mail by the forwarding entities, so they for sure can't end up all being at the bottom. Also I know Postfix makes multiline headers; these *must* be left as is. Please, append headers as they were on wire. I almost ready to explain you what happened (even I kind of did that), but until I see the mail headers in their original form, I'm not sure.

Comment: OK @NikitaKipriyanov maybe you are right ->  maybe problem is not HELO, but how to block / stop emails containning this: envelope-from=<>; receiver=<UNKNOWN> ....... ALL SPAMS which passed have same : start with (localhost.localdomain) and contain envelope-from=<>; receiver=<UNKNOWN> ... may I will have put some rule in spamassasin to solve this?

Comment: I don't see any Envelope-From header in the field. Not even empty one. Beware, you may only trust headers that were added by systems under *your* control and treat anything else as a garbage. This is why we need to know which headers are yours. Those usually on top. We need bottom-most of your headers; it contains info about the system which transferred mail to your front bastion system. You see, **the original order and look of headers is of paramount importance**, it is most important thing in debugging mail and fighting spam.

Comment: This line ..... Received-Spf: None (no SPF record) identity=helo; client-ip=78.128.76.57; helo=vps.uzhgorod.work; envelope-from=<>; receiver=<UNKNOWN>

Comment: No, this is `Recevied-Spf` header, while we need exactly `Received` header. And there is no `Envelope-From` header. That you see the same text somewhere else doesn't count.

Comment: Received headers was removed by postfix : like this https://major.io/2013/04/14/remove-sensitive-information-from-email-headers-with-postfix/

Comment: Postfix is very well written and conforming software. It surely won't remove any Received headers, as this is explicitely forbidden by the standard (RFC) I linked to. The thing you are linked to is irrelevant, as it is about originating mail (SMTPS Submission service on the port 465), not receiving it from the Internet.